# cheerio: trouble selecting meta property

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, meta, cheerio

I want to extract some metadata from html meta tags. The following meta tags are present in fetched html.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="offer"/>
<meta property="og:title" content='خانه ذرت با کورن داگ لذیذ و خوشمزه  در تهران' />
```

I have written the below sample code to get content of both **og:type** and **og:title** properties from meta tags:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var a='http://someurl/';
getDealInfo(a);


function getDealInfo(url){
    var options = {
        url: encodeURI(url),
        headers: {
            'Accept' : '*/*',
            'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
        }
    };
    request(options, function(error, response, html){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var title = $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content');
            console.log('title: ' + title);
            var type = $('meta[property="og:type"]').attr('content');
            console.log('type: ' + type);
        }else console.log('Error accessing Deal:' + response.statusCode + '\n'+error);
    });
}
```

I get **correct content** for **og:type** and **undefined** for **og:title** , though both properties are present in the fetched html.

Can someone help me figure out why I cannot get the **og:title** property content?

Comment: Hi Amir, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you possible edit your question more to include a bit more detail about what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I changed the main url according to site owner request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I note that `html` response don't have meta `og:title`

You can see this by using:

```
request(options, function(error, response, html){
    fs.writeFile('./index.html', html)
})
```

But you can use `needle` https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle package instead `request`

```
var needle = require('needle')
var results = []
needle.get(encodeURI(url), function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err
    var $ = cheerio.load(res.body)
    var title = $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content')
    results.push({
        title: title
    })
    fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(results))
})
```

Output `data.json` file with `og:title` content:

```
[
    {
        "title": "خانه ذرت با کورن داگ لذیذ و خوشمزه  در تهران"
    }
]
```